# Elliptic equations in semi-infinite strips

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, elliptic-pde, laplace-equation

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbb R^n$ with smooth boundary. Let $g=(g_{jk})_{j,k=0}^n$ be a Riemannian metric on $\mathbb R^+\times \Omega$ with smooth bounded components. Is there a good theory for existence and uniqueness of solutions to
\begin{equation}\label{pf0}
\begin{aligned}
\begin{cases}
\Delta_g u=0\,\quad &\text{on $\mathbb R^+\times \Omega$},
\\
u(t,x)=f(t,x)\,\quad &\text{on $\Sigma=\mathbb R^+\times \partial \Omega$,}\\
u(0,x)=0 \,\quad &\text{on $\Omega$.}
\end{cases}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
subject to some decay properties at infinity? For example, ideally I would like to know if there are suitable assumptions on the metric $g$ and the boundary data $f$ that guarantees existence and uniqueness of a solution $u \in L^2(\mathbb R\times \Omega)$ or perhaps some other Sobolev space with some weight representing growth or decay of solutions when $t$ approaches infinity.